# Unable to Share Image and Video on google plus

Tags: objective-c

Google plus is deprecated i am unable to share image and video. Only basic code is available for google signin. No specific code available for image and video share.

Comment: Are you trying to share from your app to Google+?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this - [Sharing images and videos to Google+ from your iOS app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/media#sharing_an_image)

It explains that to share using the native iOS app you need to have the signin (which, as you said is deprecated). You should use the code they provided.

Here is a snippet -

```
- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender { 
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance]nativeShareDialog]; 
// Set any prefilled text that you might want to suggest

 [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Achievement unlocked! I just scored 99 points. Can you beat me?"]

  NSString *fileName = @"samplemedia1";
 [shareBuilder attachImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName];

 [shareBuilder open];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. We have already implemented it in google plus sharing. But now we want to share image with basic google signin above method is deprecated in google signin. We are using the link code: "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share", with this link code i am able to share text but not image and video.